# why we are using the [continue] operator in this code?

Tags: php

i have a code that i want to know why are you use the [continue] operator for in it
note : i know what is the contiue usage but i want to know why we are using it spasifeacilly in this code so please dont reject the question or make it duplicate becaue i am prisise

```
function flatten_array(array $items,array $flattened = []){
foreach($items as $item){
   if(is_array($item)){
       $flattened = flatten_array($item,$flattened);
       continue;
   }
   $flattened[] = $item;
}
return $flattened;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `continue;` statement ensures that this part:

```
$flattened[] = $item;
```

isn't executed for sub-items that are arrays themselves.

A more familiar way to write the same function would be this:

```
function flatten_array(array $items, array $flattened = [])
{
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
            $flattened = flatten_array($item, $flattened);
        } else {
            $flattened[] = $item;
        }
    }

    return $flattened;
}
```

Comment: means that it stops the foreach loop from adding the array itsef to the flattern